# Nginx set separate browser cache expiry for Index pages

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx web server setup, where i need to specify separate browser level cache expiry (**expires**) for my index page.

What i tried

```
location =/{
 expires 1m;
 root /data/site;
 index index.htm;
}


location /{
expires 5d;
root /data/site;
 }
```

The index.htm page should have an expiry of 1m but im getting 5d in the response header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer finally. 
Had to go through the nginx workings manually.

Handling a request “/” is more complex. It is matched by the prefix location “/” only, therefore, it is handled by this location. Then the index directive tests for the existence of index files according to its parameters and the “root /data/site” directive. If the file /data/site/index.htm exists, then the directive does an internal redirect to “/index.htm”, and nginx searches the locations again **as if the request had been sent by a client**..

So I had to add one more location to search for my index.htm file

```
location ~* \index.(htm?l)$ {
  expires 1d;

  root  /data/site;
  index  index.html index.htm;
}
```